# How would I make a embedded browser in c# non-selectable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, embedded-browser

I am currently making an application for someone using an eyegaze system which tracks his eye movements to the screen and uses it as a mouse. When he hovers over a button for a little bit (.6 seconds) it sends a mouse click to the screen where he was hovering. We have an embedded browser within the application that reading the info on the browser is much more important than selecting anything on the browser and with the nature of his device, browsing is selecting if he hovers for too long. How would I go about making the content within the browser read-only, or not able to be selected?

Comment: "the application"? WinForms, WPF, something else? "embedded browser"? Default browser control, CefSharp, something else? You won't get a good answer when you leave so much guesswork.

Comment: If the control supports the events like MouseEnter/MouseLeave - you could subscribe to those to control behaviour.

Comment: It boggles the mind a bit that you can't figure out what you click on.  Arbitrarily consider Control.GetChildAtPoint(), other gui frameworks have similar methods.  If this is supposed to work for any program then you must use UI Automation, System.Windows.Automation in the C# language.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting a transparent panel over the embedded browser?  Would be like placing a piece of glass over a book.  You can still read it, but you won't be able to touch(select) the page.